# How can I install two different ipython versions

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to install two different ipython versions on a single computer. I am currently using ipython 1.1 and I cloned ipython 2.0 Dev version. So as mentioned, I tried to launch `python -m IPython notebook` from Ipython 2.0 folder but I cannot import ipython 2 specific module like `widget`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to do this, is to use virtualenvironments. Check out [invewrapper](https://github.com/berdario/invewrapper) or its predecessor [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

Once you have either installed, make two virtualenvironments (`pew-new old_ipython` and `pew-new new_ipython`), activate each (creating one will activate it automatically) and install your desired version of IPython.